# Laravel form submission issues

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, submit

I have tried to resolve this before posting and I know this is a simple question but I'm still having trouble.

I've created a form that submits terms using a post and then attempting to run a route that calls a function within a controller which then redirects the user to the correct page using the previously submitted term. What is happening is i"m being redirected to a page has expired.

If there is a better way to do this I'm up for trying that to.

Here is the code.

```
<form action="/search" method="post" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
<input type="text" name="term" size="40" id="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Web route

```
Route::post('/search', 'MovieSearchController@search')->name('searchResults');
```

Controller - atm i'm testing to see if this is being called, which it is not.

```
public function search(ServerRequestInterface $request)
{
    $term = 'potatos';
    return redirect('/search/' . $term);
}
```

Comment: What does a form id have to do with anything?

Comment: show your get route code for 'search'

Comment: The function in the top post that contains the code has it "public function search" unless i'm missing a lot more code than I should :-/

Comment: you want to redirect this to "search/$term" as you write this " return redirect('/search/' . $term); "   ?  so for that you have write code in route file for get route 'search'with variable check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i see your form does not have a CSRF token field.

Add one by using `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: it trow error if csrf required , you can disable it if you needed

Comment: Hes submitting a form. It should not be disabled.

Comment: yes that what we shouldn't do it but it's not like it's mandatory

Comment: Why would you even consider not using it?

Comment: i think he disable it because he not having error over it, his query is about not redirected properly

Comment: No I wasn't award I needed this. I think I saw it somewhere in the documents but passed over it. This fixed the problem. I'm going to look over the documents now to make sure I don't miss something else

Comment: @user873684 just a tip use try catch in your code so that you know whats your actual error is.